# Producing messages randomly over partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I don't set key while sending messages. Do I have guarantees that messages will go to partititions randomly ? If not how can I achieve this ? I want be sure that my consumers (in one cusumer group) will be evenly loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a key, your Kafka Producer will - by default - apply a [RoundRobinPartitioner](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/RoundRobinPartitioner.html) which will distribute the messages accross the partitions evenly.

If you are looking for a pure "random" Partitioner you could write a custom Partitioner that assigns a partition randomly.

Comment: Since when roundrobin = random? ;-)

Comment: Yes, true @mazaneicha have clarified it and was understanding "randomly" to be equal to "evenly distributed" which is of course not the same :)

Comment: Ok, so if I want random distribution I must implement own Partitioner.

Comment: To me, it is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve. If you want your "consumer groups be evenly loaded" then the default partitioner (RoundRobin) is sufficient. If you want to implement a *random* partitioner which will (based on the Random implementation) lead again to your consumer groups being evenly loaded you need to implement a custom partitioner.

Comment: Ok so maybe one again. As you noticed I don't really need random distribution. But I have some fears how round robing algorithm here really works.. Each, one message go to next parition ? Or maybe it is some time slot for it ? If I have 3 partitions, 3 message sending in same milisecond - have i qurantee that it not be in same partition ? (of course in "random solution" i dont have qurantee, but i have same propability)

Comment: No, for 3 messages being sent within the same millisecond there is no guarantee. Keep in mind, that Kafka batches some messages before the they get send to the broker. However, in the long-run your messages will be evenly distributed accross the partitions. Not for just 3 messages!

Comment: So, as I thought i can't use round robin algorithm. I some edge case my producer will send only few messages (and have some break), and i really don't want that one cosumer process all this messages. So i thing random solution is good idea. Should i really implement own partitioner, or maybe giving some key - random UID - will be sufficient ?

Comment: Yes, a UUID as key should be fine. Remember that if you have a key, Kafka will by default apply the following logic to partition the data: `kafka.common.utils.Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;`